# Relevance of the Jahn-Teller theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, group-theory, molecules, ground-state

[Jahn and Teller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect) stated in their paper that

> All non-linear nuclear configurations are therefore unstable for an orbitally degenerate electronic state. Thus if we know of a polyatomic molecule that the nuclei in the equilibrium configuration do not all lie on a straight line, then we know at the same time that its electronic ground state does not possess orbital degeneracy.

The problem is, even if the nuclei form a very symmetric configuration, generally we do not expect the ground state to be degenerate. Excited states could be degenerate, but the ground state is generally non-degenerate, right? Ground state degeneracy implies the possibility of spontaneous symmetry breaking, which is common for an infinite system but rare for a finite system, right?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with what you say. Generally speaking, QM dislikes degenerate states (not only lowest lying ones) and tries to push them apart as a response to some (unavoidable) corrections to the bare Hamiltonian.

A special case occurs when the degeneracy is enforced by some symmetry. Then degeneracy survives, although, symmetries are also never "really-really-really" exact. So even those "protected" degeneracies are lifted at the end of the day, although the actual splitting magnitude can be exponentially small.

To my understanding these considerations form the physical content of Nernst's theorem (3rd Law of Thermodynamics).